# Download PDF File from Shared Network Drive in .NET Core 3.1 Web Api

Tags: c#, download, webapi

I have unsuccessfully tried several different ways to do this with no luck.

The download controller is passed a base 64 encrypted shared file path. When decrypted it looks something like this:

```
\\service_cifs01\vol1\Department_A1\images\00\00\02\83.pdf
```

This is my download code:

```
var @decodedFile = Base64Decode(path);
var memory = new MemoryStream();
await using (var stream = new FileStream(@decodedFile, FileMode.Open)) {
    await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
}
memory.Position = 0;
return File(memory, GetContentType(@decodedFile), decodedFile);
```

The file does exist, but I get this error message:

```
File \\service_cifs01\vol1\Department_A1\images\00\00\02\83.pdf was not found.
Exception: Access to the path '\\service_cifs01\vol1\Department_A1\images\00\00\02\83.pdf' is denied.
```

Can anyone show me how I could do this?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know under which user context the app is running and what are the permissions for the shared drive. Could you please check the effective file permissions?